# keras OOM with a tiny model and batch_size 1

Tags: tensorflow, keras, memory, out-of-memory

I am getting a keras OOM error immediately after model creation, during first call to predict

weights and activations are all tiny, i cannot understand the source of the OOM

```
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

up1, up2, up3 = [
    tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), interpolation="nearest", name=f"up{i}")
    for i in range(3)
]


c1, c2 = [
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        filters=5,
        kernel_size=3,
        use_bias=False,
        name=f"conv{i}",
    )
    for i in range(2)
]

m = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        up1,
        c1,
        up2,
        c2,
        up3,
    ]
)

m.predict(tf.zeros((1_500, 97, 97, 1)), batch_size=1, verbose=1).shape
```

this function processes ~1350 batches of size 1 and quits

```
1367/1500 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s
```

```
ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,5,384,384] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node sequential/conv1/Conv2D-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
 [Op:__inference_predict_function_159]

Function call stack:
predict_function
```

Before creating the model, there's plenty of RAM

```
Memory-Usage
377MiB / 16280MiB
```

After i create the model, not so much

`15781MiB / 16280MiB`

I can't understand why such a small model would use all the RAM, would welcome any suggestions to reduce the RAM usage

using tensorflow 2.5.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 (official tf docker with own conda env)
NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0

Comment: Is the memory listed video memory or CPU memory?

Comment: this is gpu memory, reported by `nvidia-smi`

Comment: are you sure the problem is about the data and not the model? to me it seems that the images are taking all the space

Comment: >seems that the images are taking all the space\

interesting, the output would be just around 3.6 GB in this situation, perhaps it's contributing, hasn't been a problem before but is worth looking in to, thanks!